# Distributing hairs evenly along the surface

Tags: particles, hair, procedural

I have UV sphere inside of which I distributed stars-spheres as hairs. But their current positions leaves a lot of blank black spots which maybe seem organic but I don't like. Is there any way to distribute them more evenly? It also seems to be what radius option in children depends on emitter size and it's scaling doesn't allow to get bigger radius option. Or am I wrong? [image: Stars] [image: Settings] [image: Solid] [image: Solid sphere]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for even distribution. It is located under the advanced settings.

[image: Advanced Settings Panel]